# Как правильно пишется слово МАШИНОПРОВЕРЯЕМЫЙ?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно пишется слово *МАШИНОПРОВЕРЯЕМЫЙ* (количество Н в первом корне, наличие/отсутствие дефиса) в смысле:

> свойство данных, информации быть проверяемыми компьютером (машиной) с использованием алгоритма

Нашёл ближайшую аналогию:

> Аннотации особенно широко применяются в библиотеках и API, поскольку там они служат также **машинно-верифицируемой** документацией

Но и там нет уверенности в корректности написания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В написании этого слова по существующим правилам возможны колебания.

**1) Н или НН?**

Проверяемый машиной — машинопроверяемый; проверяемый машинным способом — машиннопроверяемый.

Конечно, из этих вариантов логично выбрать ***машинопроверяемый***, он поддерживается таким словом, как ***машиносчитываемый***, тогда пишем одну букву Н. http://airspot.ru/book/file/758/9303_p1_v2_cons_ru.pdf

***Машинно-верифицируемыый*** соотносится с такими сочетаниями, как машинная верификация, верификация машинным способом, отсюда две буквы НН.

**2) Слитно или дефис?**

В принципе все варианты должны писаться слитно, так как мы имеем сложное слово, образованное **сложением наречия и прилагательного.**

Однако в **специальной** литературе достаточно часто встречается дефисное написание **терминов**, если при слитном написании их сложно прочитать. Поэтому выбираем вариант ***машинно-верифицируемыый***.

Также еще раз отметим, что **при дефисном написание две буквы НН выглядят более привычно**   (через дефис обычно пишутся сложные прилагательные, в которых первая основа является основой прилагательного, а не существительного).

Итак, **машинопроверяемый, машиносчитываемый, машинно-верифицируемыый.**

Comment: Пока, думаю, остановлюсь на варианте *машинно-проверяемый*, т.к. это и есть русскоязычный вариант слова *машинно-верифицируемый* и логично к нему применить те же принципы.

Comment: Возможно, Вы правы, в паре они неплохо смотрятся. Кроме того, "машинопроверяемый" имеет не очень ясную семантику: проверяем машину или проверяем машиной.

Comment: Семантика будет хорошо ясна из контекста (заголовок научной статьи). Но тут очень хорошо работают аргументы в пользу варианта с дефисом с точки зрения простоты прочтения и восприятия.

Comment: @Денис Кулагин В таком случае желаю Вам успехов и всегда рада Вам помочь.

Comment: Вам спасибо за развёрнутый ответ.